# Add columns in master project from external project tasks

Tags: ms-project

I have created a master project ( in ms project 2010 and published in ms epm 2013)that contains only key milestones tasks from external projects. Hence this master project plan contains high level milestones of overall Program and external projects' milestones.

I need to know how I can add additional columns like project status, division and project manager name, RAG status with color in this master project for the external tasks.

By introducing these columns I will be able to track with respective project owner to track for any delay or other related correspondence.

I need to know how to do this for managing projects portfolio in ms epm 2013.